# Game invite for non-hosted game

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-ui

I'm working on a game using Facebook, but not hosted by Facebook. One of the things I would like to do is to invite other people via Facebook to play a game. I've found the invite API, that looks something like this:

```
FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
    message: 'Some message goes here',
}, 
function(response){
    // Do stuff here
}
);
```

Ideally I would like clicking on the link from that invitation to go to my web site, but there doesn't seem to be a way to do that. Am I missing something completely, or does this just not seem to do what I think it should at all?

Comment: You are not allowed to use this kind of request to redirect users off of Facebook. These requests are supposed to take the user to the Web Games platform version of your app, resp. be handled in the mobile version of it.

Comment: That wasn't entirely clear from the documents, at least not until I was really getting down in to the weeds. Still, thanks!